# can't catch SIGTERM sent by upstart in golang

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, signals

I have an upstart job running (some kind of TCP server). occasionally my process get restarted and I can see the next line in my syslog:

```
kernel: [2422352.460162] init: <job_name> main process (16545) killed by TERM signal
```

I don't understand the reason for this TERM signal by the kernel so I decided to catch the signal and print some memory and goroutines statistics before I terminate.
so now my code looks like this:

```
func main() {
   sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
   signal.Notify(sigc, syscall.SIGTERM)
   go func() {
      s := <-sigc
      numOfGoRoutines := runtime. NumGoroutine()
      var stats runtime.MemStats
      runtime.ReadMemStats(&stats)
      log.Println("Got Signal ", s)
      log.Println("num of goroutines: ", numOfGoRoutines)
      log.Println("Memory Allocated: ",  stats.Alloc)
      os.Exit(1)
   }()
   someInfiniteLoopFunction() // this function defined in a different file.
```

now the weird thing is that my goroutine doesn't catch the TERM signal even when I manually stop the job.
even more interesting is the fact that if I add a Sleep for 100 seconds right after signal handler goroutine and stop the job during this sleep period then my goroutine DOES catch the TERM signal.
I'm absolutely clueless here and will appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you certain that you're *not* catching the `TERM` signal? Maybe the output is getting dropped by upstart. Try logging to a file.

Comment: @JimB man you were right! I managed to write to file. why does upstart drop the outptut? Thank You!

Comment: Upstart's `wait` call probably returns while the output is buffered somewhere, and gets discarded. A small sleep may help, but there's no way to make it foolproof.

Answer (score -1):

**UPD.** Sorry, I read it correctly now. Maybe your goroutine don't wait signal and execute `os.Exit()`. Try to add another chan.

```
func main() {
   sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
   done := make(chan bool, 1)
   signal.Notify(sigc, syscall.SIGTERM)
   go func() {

      s := <-sigc
      numOfGoRoutines := runtime. NumGoroutine()
      var stats runtime.MemStats
      runtime.ReadMemStats(&stats)
      log.Println("Got Signal ", s)
      log.Println("num of goroutines: ", numOfGoRoutines)
      log.Println("Memory Allocated: ",  stats.Alloc)
      done <- true
      os.Exit(1)
   }()
   <-done
   someInfiniteLoopFunction() // this function defined in a different file.
```

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate? what different will it make if I add this defer?

Comment: this has nothing to do with a panic

Comment: @makhov but why shouldn't it wait? also, as I mentioned, if I add a sleep right after my goroutine and call stop I do manage to catch the signal.

Comment: this still doesn't do anything, because you can't ever get to the main loop.